# How to wrap built-in methods in Python? (or 'how to pass them by reference')

Tags: python, exception, wrapper

I want to wrap the default open method with a wrapper that should also catch exceptions. Here's a test example that **works**:

```
truemethod = open
def fn(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return truemethod(*args, **kwargs)
    except (IOError, OSError):
        sys.exit('Can\'t open \'{0}\'. Error #{1[0]}: {1[1]}'.format(args[0], sys.exc_info()[1].args))

open = fn
```

I want to make a generic method of it:

```
def wrap(method, exceptions = (OSError, IOError)):
    truemethod = method
    def fn(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return truemethod(*args, **kwargs)
        except exceptions:
            sys.exit('Can\'t open \'{0}\'. Error #{1[0]}: {1[1]}'.format(args[0], sys.exc_info()[1].args))

    method = fn
```

But it doesn't work:

```
>>> wrap(open)
>>> open
<built-in function open>
```

Apparently, `method` is a copy of the parameter, not a reference as I expected. Any pythonic workaround?

Comment: there is a good answer and I put a comment there how you do if you really want to replace `__builtin__.open` (bad bad bad). I just wanted to point out that you confuse Python's names for objects with variables here. `open = ..` only (re)binds the name `open` in the scope where you assign it; what you didn't do was rebinding the builtin name `open`. perhaps you thought `open` was an object that you could change by assignment, but in Python there are no such objects.

Comment: Thanks, now it's making sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that inside `wrap`, your `method = fn` statement is simply changing the local value of `method`, it isn't changing the larger value of `open`.  You'll have to assign to those names yourself:

```
def wrap(method, exceptions = (OSError, IOError)):
    def fn(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return method(*args, **kwargs)
        except exceptions:
            sys.exit('Can\'t open \'{0}\'. Error #{1[0]}: {1[1]}'.format(args[0], sys.exc_info()[1].args))

    return fn

open = wrap(open)
foo = wrap(foo)
```

Comment: +1, that's the good solution. Except to be even more general, the message shouldn't mention "Can't open" (was already in the OP's post, I know).

Comment: Ok, so basically it can serve as a decorator for my own methods.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `global open`.  In the general case, you might want to look at [this section of the manual](http://docs.python.org/library/__builtin__.html):

> This module provides direct access to all ‘built-in’ identifiers of Python; for example, `__builtin__.open` is the full name for the built-in function [open()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open). See chapter [Built-in Objects](http://docs.python.org/library/objects.html#builtin).
>
> This module is not normally accessed explicitly by most applications, but can be useful in modules that provide objects with the same name as a built-in value, but in which the built-in of that name is also needed. For example, in a module that wants to implement an open() function that wraps the built-in [open()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open), this module can be used directly:
>
> ```
> import __builtin__
>
> def open(path):
>     f = __builtin__.open(path, 'r')
>     return UpperCaser(f)
>
> class UpperCaser:
>     '''Wrapper around a file that converts output to upper-case.'''
>
>     def __init__(self, f):
>         self._f = f
>
>     def read(self, count=-1):
>         return self._f.read(count).upper()
>
>     # ...
> ```
>
> CPython implementation detail: Most modules have the name `__builtins__` (note the 's') made available as part of their globals. The value of `__builtins__` is normally either this module or the value of this modules’s `__dict__` attribute. Since this is an implementation detail, it may not be used by alternate implementations of Python.

Comment: That seems a bit specific for the generic case.

Comment: Ouch, so you mean to replace that for _any_ access to the `open` function? Doesn't sound like what the OP wants at all, it's not a wrapper but a global change.

Comment: @RedGlyph: Well, yes, that's how I interpreted the original question.

Comment: it's not hard but it's evil. place `_oldopen = __builtin__.open` then `__builtin__.open = open` right in the module code quoted here, and you have replaced it everywhere. Except those who imported it by `from __builtin__ import open`  before this module was imported.

Comment: (ah, wait.. save old open in `_oldopen` before you implement the replacement, and call the oldone by `_oldopen` of course, to avoid recursion! :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can just add `return fn` at the end of your `wrap` function and then do:

```
>>> open = wrap(open)
>>> open('bhla')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
    open('bhla')
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 7, in fn
    sys.exit('Can\'t open \'{0}\'. Error #{1[0]}: {1[1]}'.format(args[0], sys.exc_info()[1].args))
SystemExit: Can't open 'bhla'. Error #2: No such file or directory
```